# Why can't I prevent reporting KeyboardInterrupt stack traces in asyncio tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Hmm.... here's a puzzle. Why is it that if a `asyncio.Task` throws an exception, I can catch the exception in the coroutine awaiting the task, and avoid reporting a stack trace for that exception, but not for `KeyboardInterrupt`?

```
class CatchAsyncTest(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_catch(self):
        async def e(clz):
            raise clz()

        try:
            
            try:
                # t = asyncio.Task(e(asyncio.CancelledError))  # Can catch and not report stack trace
                # t = asyncio.Task(e(TypeError))               # Can catch and not report stack trace
                t = asyncio.Task(e(KeyboardInterrupt))       # Can catch, but always reports stack trace
                await t
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, asyncio.CancelledError, TypeError) as e:
                # t.set_exception(None) # Nope!
                print(f"done={t.done()} Caught", type(e), file=sys.stderr)
                # raise TypeError()
                # Not rethrown
                
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print("@@@", type(e), file=sys.stderr)  # Never reached
```

reports:

```
done=True Caught <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../tests.py", line 215, in e
    raise clz()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

For other exceptions:

```
done=True Caught <class 'TypeError'>
```

(no stack trace is printed).

Python 3.8

Comment: Since the keyboard isn't associated with a particular task, keyboard interrupts are sent to the original foreground task.

Comment: I don't understand  - KeyboardInterrupt (and also the other exceptions) are all raised during the execution of the Task.
All are rethrown to the awaiting coroutine (test_catch).  Only KeyboardInterrupt can't have its stack trace suppressed through. Why.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the output.

Comment: There is something "different" about `KeyboardInterrupt` in `asyncio`. If you look at the cpython source code, you'll see it's being treated like `SystemExit` frequently, which is to say: not like other exceptions. If you wrap `asyncio.run()` with a `try`/`except KeyboardInterrupt:`, or wrap `loop.run_forever()` or whatever is _outside_ a coroutine/task, then you can suppress it.